# Certain divs in header and footer aren't responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm having trouble making my header responsive. When I view the site from a full-sized browser window, or from a phone, it's fine. (I've got "@media only" queries set up for mobile.) But if I adjust my browser window to anything in between the two, the div on the left side of the header runs into the one on the right.

I have a feeling it's because I've inserted the logo into the website via the header.php file. If it wasn't there, I'm sure the header would be responsive.

How do you handle this? Is there some "@media only" query I can set up to address the in-between browser sizes?

You can view the test site in question here: http://kahamarketing.com/wyckoff/wordpress/

I'm having a similar problem with the three banners in the footer, which run into one another if I make my browser window any smaller. Similarly, I added these elements through the website's footer.php file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in your case the height rule for `a.logo` makes it broken. take out the line with `height: 60px`

maybe after that you need to take out the `margin-top` rule for `nav.navigation`

for your footer problem it is a bit more complicated.
hard to explain without knowing how much you actually know about CSS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set the a.logo height to auto and took out the margin-top rule. This seemed to tidy things up a bit when it comes to resizing the browser window. Now the text resizes to fit within the confines of the window.

The title still runs into the navigation bar when I resize it. Any idea why this is?

I'm on the border between beginner and intermediate when it comes to CSS knowledge. Things get wonky when I have to try making things responsive.